# When could a call to time(NULL) fail on Linux

Tags: c, time

According to this documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/

for time(NULL) "If the function could not retrieve the calendar time, it returns a -1 value."

Is this something I should check for in my code? Surely something has got to be going pretty wrong if time(NULL) is not retrieving the time.

Comment: When there's a severe power outage or when your computer crashes... ;) ... you put it in a finally block right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may be running on an embedded device that doesn't have a real-time clock.

The glibc source code claims that the time syscall can't fail on Linux:

```
 time_t res = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (time, err, 1, NULL);
  /* There cannot be any error.  */
```

and indeed this is the case if you look at the kernel source:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(time, time_t __user *, tloc)
{
        time_t i = get_seconds();

        if (tloc) {
                if (put_user(i,tloc))
                        return -EFAULT;
        }
        force_successful_syscall_return();
        return i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu man page says `time(2)` can fail due to `EFAULT` ("`t` points outside your accessible address space").

OSX man page says it can fail for the same reasons as `gettimeofday`, which are `EFAULT` and `EPERM` (not sure how this applies to `time`).

Therefore, it cannot fail for the argument of `NULL`, according to the documentation of aforementioned systems.

Also, [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/time.html) specifies no error conditions at all for this function.

Comment: The question is about when t is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You have something called a system clock. If that's broken, then this will fail, though there could be many other reasons.

Comment: How can the system clock "break"? I've seen it lose time, gain time, and behave abnormally. But I've never seen it not work at all.

Comment: Reference to atomice's post : If you use this for say --- the nds (www.devkitpro.com) then it *CAN* (Downvoter explain yourself)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious case would be a system whose internal clock requires external initialization (using eg. NTP). Until this has happened, the internal clock cannot give epoch-relative values, although it can be used to measure intervals. `time_t` is epoch-relative and therefore `time(NULL)` must fail in this case.

Comment: wouldn't time(NULL) just give the wrong answer here?  Rather than failing and returning -1?

Comment: No, not if it's properly implemented. That's quite reasonable. Consider an OS that implements a `/dev/time/` deivce, which when read gives the current time. Until initialized, you'd get a read error on the device. A standard C lib would pass on that failure when calling `time()`